# Why didn't using boost regex library get unresolved external error?

Tags: boost

I was just playing with **regex  library of boost**. During build process, I didn't specify the *location* and the *library name* and surprisingly I got this error :

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib'
```

I just set where the boost libs are and the error disappeared! ( I didn't say anything about its name,  libboost_regex-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib)
Usually when I linked a library to my project and I forgot to specify its name and its location I got a **unresolved externals** error. It was required to specify library name along with its location, But by using boost this is not the case any more. So what's the reason? How can I create a library that is just necessary to include its interface and specify its location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Auto-Linking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#auto-linking):

> Most Windows compilers and linkers have so-called “auto-linking support,” which eliminates the second challenge. Special code in Boost header files detects your compiler options and uses that information to encode the name of the correct library into your object files; the linker selects the library with that name from the directories you've told it to search.